# Want to move from web services to Web API. How to go about this?

Tags: rest, soap, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

So right now our company has custom SOAP web services that hold functions to do things (e.g. sending emails, getting employee info, etc.) and are connected via Service References.

We want to make the switch to Web API 2, but I'm kind of lost on how we can (or if it's possible) to do that since all of our services interact with SOAP.

I wanted to create brand new Web APIs for each service we have which would hold the methods, but I'm not sure where to start. I've scoured the internet, but I haven't really found anything that answers my question.

Can someone shed some light on this for me? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

well, you can create the Web API Service, and exposes the functions that you need, maybe, this service can be accessed from anywhere, but, the real functionality is on the soap (that can be in a DMZ for example), so, create a class library that consume those services and Web API now use this class library, so Web API will be only a facade.

But, first think, is really necessary have this facade in web api to consume those services?

Remember that if your soap services are built with WCF, WCF has support for HTTP protocol.